# Public facing website design

Tags: web-applications, playframework

I am using Play web framework 1.2.4.

I have user profiles in my application and want to open it to people who are not logged in.

So something like if my site is http://www.testsite.com

I want  htp://www.testsite.com/user1 to show user1's profile, htp://www.testsite.com/user2 show user2's profile and so on for all users. Like how facebook has done it.

Could you please suggest what is the best way of doing this and how can then I make google and other search engine index the profile pages.

"htp" above in url is actually http. It won't let me submit question if I have more than 2 urls.

Thanks,
Sawan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, first of all, create a controller method that serves the site you would like to see when the user goes to www.testsite.com/user1. Let's say this is `bar(String username)` method in `Foo` controller. So you have something like:

```
public class Foo extends Controller {

    public static void bar(String username) {
        // Do something in here and render the response. I will just render a sample text here.
        renderText("Hello " + username + "!");
    }

}
```

Now you just need to set up the routes. So in routes file, put something like this:

```
GET     /{username}         Foo.bar(username)
```

Remember that order of the routes in the routes file matters, so make sure this route is at the bottom, so that a route like `/edit/{id}` is defined before this route. Otherwise play may resolve request to `site.com/edit/123` into calling `Foo.bar("edit/123")` instead of calling some `Foo2.edit(123)` method, which is probably not what you want in most cases.

When you try this and go to `http://localhost:9000/sawan` now, this should show `Hello sawan!`.
Add the appropriate models and code and you can now show whatever you want on that page.

As for the google indexing, the crawler needs to be able to discover these user pages. You may create a sitemap and add it to google(http://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=156184). To make it update dynamically, you may need to create an index of these user pages and make it accessible to google, e.g. via the sitemap, or link on main page, etc. But I am no expert in SEO, so you may be better of with googling some more information yourself.

Comment: Exactly what I need. I will play around for good search engine index. Thanks.